# EF Migration - Micro Serivces - Fetch Value from DB1 and Update in DB2 using EF Migration (for Patching the data, as one time)

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, standards, entity-framework-migrations

We have Micro Services, M1, M2, M3 etc. Each has its own database and using EF migration we manage the scripts for each database.

Now our requirement is to pull some value from M1DB (MicroService Database1) and update into M2DB (Microservice database2). This is a one-time activity to patch some value.

We need to handle all scripts only through EF Migration. No Manual scripts updates. What is the **industry standard** to achieve this? Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank You